# mosquitto self signed certificate issue - handshake failure

Tags: ssl, mqtt, self-signed

I've created self signed CA and certs for mosquito acording to: 
https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html and 
http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/

Then added these to mosquitto dir and chmoded for mosquitto user, generally did that all with script which runs commands to:
 - Create CA
 - Create server certs
 - Create client certs

```
#!/bin/bash
# FROM: https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html and
# http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/
set -e

# logging
RESTORE='\033[0m'

RED='\033[00;31m'
GREEN='\033[00;32m'
YELLOW='\033[00;33m'
BLUE='\033[00;34m'
PURPLE='\033[00;35m'
CYAN='\033[00;36m'
LIGHTGRAY='\033[00;37m'

LRED='\033[01;31m'
LGREEN='\033[01;32m'
LYELLOW='\033[01;33m'
LBLUE='\033[01;34m'
LPURPLE='\033[01;35m'
LCYAN='\033[01;36m'
WHITE='\033[01;37m'

REQNUM=0

print_err() {
    echo -e "${RED}ERROR $@ ${RESTORE}"
}

print_succ() {
    echo -e "${GREEN} SUCCES: $@ ${RESTORE}"
}

print_warn() {
    echo -e "${BLUE} WARN: $@ ${RESTORE}"
}


# CA & SRV need to have different params for mosquitto broker to work & to avoid needles asking
SUBJ="-subj "'/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O='"$((++REQNUM))$1"'/OU=IT_Department/CN=localhost.local'

# gen CA
gen_CA() {
    print_warn "generate CA"
    openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096
    openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -sha256 ${DAYS} -out ca.crt ${SUBJ}
}

# SERVER
gen_server_keys() {
    print_warn "Generate a server key"
    openssl genrsa ${PSWD} -out server.key 2048 ${SUBJ}
    print_warn "Generate a certificate signing request to send to the CA"
    openssl req -out server.csr -key server.key -new ${SUBJ}
    print_warn "Send the CSR to the CA, or sign it with your CA key"
    openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt ${DAYS}
}

# CLIENT
gen_client_keys() {
    print_warn "Generate a client key"
    openssl genrsa ${PSWD} -out client.key 2048 ${SUBJ} 
    print_warn " Generate a certificate signing request to send to the CA"
    openssl req -out client.csr -key client.key -new ${SUBJ}
    print_warn "Send the CSR to the CA, or sign it with your CA key"
    openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key  -addtrust clientAuth -CAcreateserial -out client.crt ${DAYS}
}

mosq_install() {
    print_warn "Install mqtt certs"
    sudo systemctl stop mosquitto
    sudo cp server.* ca.crt /etc/mosquitto/certs/
    sudo chown -R mosquitto:mosquitto /etc/mosquitto/certs
    sudo bash -c 'cat << EOF > /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/tls.conf
listener 8883
tls_version tlsv1.2
require_certificate false
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
EOF'
    sudo chown -R mosquitto:mosquitto /etc/mosquitto/certs/ /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
    sudo systemctl restart mosquitto && print_warn "MQTT restarted!"
}

print_help() {
    echo "usage: "
    echo "--CA or --SRV or --CLI"
    echo "--des3 to use passwd on cers"
    echo "--days 'N' to use expirydate"
    echo "--mosq install to mosquitto certs"
}

[ $1 ] || print_help

for a in $@; do 
    case "$a" in
        "--CA")
            gen_CA && print_succ "CA" || print_err "CA failed"
            ;;
        "--SRV")
            gen_server_keys  && print_succ "server" || print_err "server keys failed"
            ;;
        "--CLI")
            gen_client_keys && print_succ "cli" || print_err "client keys failed"
            ;;
        "--pass")
            PSWD="-des3"
            ;;
        "--days")
            DAYS="-days $2"
            shift
            ;;
        "--mosq")
            mosq_install && print_succ "" || print_err "install mosquitto"
            ;;
        -h|--help)
            print_help
            ;;
        *)
            print_help;
            echo "bad param! $a"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

After that I get error in mosquitto logs:

> 159 1528809795: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
>    160 1528809795: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
>    161 1528809795: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
>    162 1528809806: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 8883.
>    163 1528809806: OpenSSL Error: error:14094418:SSL   routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
>    164 1528809806: OpenSSL Error: error:140940E5:SSL   routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl handshake failure
>    165 1528809806: Socket error on client , disconnecting.
>    166 1528809809: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 8883

mosquitto.conf

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/                                                                                                             
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

In sourced conf.d dir tls.conf:

```
listener 8883                                                                                                                                                          
tls_version tlsv1.2
require_certificate true
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
```

mosquitto_sub command to test:
`mosquitto_sub -h localhost -p 8883 --cafile ca.crt  -v -t '#'`

The only issue in I get with openssl s_client I get is:
"verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)"
I can't connect with either python paho mqtt, or mosquitto_sub/pub. I've wanted to test connections on localhost, then make certs for my local network server and use it with my devices for testing - but can't make it connect even on localhost.

Comment: Edit the question to show your mosquitto.conf so we can see how you have set up the certificates and also include the mosquitto_sub command you are using.

Comment: Added mosquitto config and mosquitto_sub commands